# Return byte offset and line matching expression on a block device?

Tags: linux, perl, grep

I would like to run a scan on a block device (/dev/sdb) to find an expression "some text" and return the expression's line "This is **some text** I found." as well as its offset in bytes :

32768 -  This is some text I found.

I have tried to use `grep -a --byte-offset "some text" /dev/sdb` but I run into a `grep:line too long` error.

I know my LINE_MAX is 2048 so I would like to know how to raise that limit to some arbitrarily large value or maybe replace this function in PERL?

Thanks!

Comment: C might be a better option here in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Untested and probably sub-optimal even if correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;

{
        use bytes;
        open my $h, '<', '/dev/sdb';

        my $offset = 0;

        while (my $line = <$h>) {
                while ($line =~ /ext?/g) {
                        printf "Line: %d\tByte: %d\n", $., $offset + $-[0];
                }
                $offset += length $line;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sinan, thanks for your help! I dont know perl so I am going to run it and see where it gets me. Im learning :). Just one quick question, where do I specify the expression I am looking for?

Comment: The pattern above is `/ext?/g` That is, the string `'ex'` followed by zero or one `t`. Given that you are reading large binary data, "lines" may be really long. The proper way to do this is to `sysread` fixed size chunks, but then you have to be careful about partial matches at the end of each chunk etc, but that would keep memory use predictable whereas with this code, it would fluctuate wildly.